# EXTJS 4.0 grid in an inactive tab shows nothing

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I create a tab panel with two tabs, first one is active and second isn't.

Then I create two grids and render them to first tab content and second tab content.

The first tab shows fine, and the inactive one shows nothing but only the gird layout appears.

I tried to put two grids into the active tab, and it works.

But I want each tab to contain one grid, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us some code please?

Comment: i found that i can only fixed the issue by creating a listener to listen the active tab and add the grid inside dynamically